# Using Boost strong typedef with unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I am using a Boost strong typedef to strong-type `uint64_t`:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(uint64_t, MyInt)
```

and an `std::unordered_map` using this:

```
std::unordered_map<MyInt, int> umap;
```

Unfortunately I get a lot of compiler errors (can't paste here as they're on another machine):

```
error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
.static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>)

error: use of deleted function 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_ebo_helper

_Hashtable() = default;
```

(+ a lot more I cannot type)

Using a Boost strong type as the key definitely causes the problem because if I remove the `unordered_map` I get no compiler errors.

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear: there is no hash function for your type `MyInt` and `std::unordered_map` requires `std::hash<KeyType>{}` to exist (or another has function to be set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) about `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`, it is clearly mentioned that it defines a new type wrapping the target inner type (it is not a simple alias).

Knowing that, there is no defined `std::hash<MyInt>` specialization available (required by `std::unordered_map<MyInt, int>`) since `MyInt` is now a distinct type from `uint64_t`.

You just need to provide one and it should work as expected.

For instance:

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<MyInt>
    {
        size_t operator()(const MyInt & m) const
        {
            return hash<uint64_t>{}(m);
        }
    };
}
```

---

***Edit:***

As pointed out in comments, you could also directly pass the proper `std::hash<>` specialization to use from the `std::unordered_map<>` instantiation as the third template parameter since `MyInt` is implicitly convertible to `uint64_t` (as mentioned in the boost documentation as well).

It would then become:

```
std::unordered_map<MyInt, int, std::hash<uint64_t>> umap;
```

No need to define your own `std::hash<MyInt>` specialization anymore.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/4G7oq93zP or https://godbolt.org/z/7crE7qdW5

Comment: @MarekR Nice catch ! I'll edit the answer accordingly